# Laravel 4 : How to combine where and with in eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I want a json for the currently logged in user with his checklist(s). How do I combine ::where and ::with?

This gives me the currently logged in user:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->user_id)->get();
```

This gives me all the users and their checklist(s):

```
$user = User::with('checklists')->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User::with()` will return an Eloquent query object, so

```
$user = User::with('checklists')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->user_id)
    ->get();
```